# plot a stacked bar chart in matlab that shows all the values

Tags: matlab, bar-chart, stackedbarseries

Hi I have the following code in Matlab

```
CC_monthly_thermal_demand = [495 500 500 195 210 100 70 65 85 265 320 430]';
AD_monthly_thermal_generation_250 = [193 193 193 193 193 193 193 193 193 193 193 193]';
figure;
bar(1:12,AD_monthly_thermal_generation_250)
hold on
bar(1:12,CC_monthly_thermal_demand,'r')
set(gca,'XTickLabel',{'Jan', 'Feb', 'Mar', 'Apr', 'May', 'Jun', 'Jul', 'Aug',' Sep', 'Oct', 'Nov',' Dec'},'FontSize',18)
title('Seasonal Anaerobic Digestion (250kWe) Thermal Energy Supply to Demand - 2012','FontSize',22)
ylabel('Thermal Energy (MWhe)')
legend('250 kWth Supply','Thermal Energy Demand')
grid on
axis([0 13 0 600])
```

I am trying to plot a stacked bar chart that shows the colour of each variable for every bar. However, for the bars where the "AD_monthly_thermal_generation_250" is a lower value than the "CC_monthly_thermal_demand" the "AD_monthly_thermal_generation_250" colour is completely covered by the "CC_monthly_thermal_demand" and so I can't see these values. Is it possible to be able to see them?

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Combine the inputs together such that each series is a column, then use the option `'stack'`:

```
A = [495 500 500 195 210 100 70 65 85 265 320 430]';
B = [193 193 193 193 20  193 193 193 193 193 193 193]';
bar([B,A],'stacked')
```

**EDIT** addressing comment:

```
% Create random data and filler
A      = randi(100,10,1);
B      = randi(100,10,1);
mxA    = max(A);
filler = mxA-A;

% Plot stacked bar chart
h = bar([A,filler,B],'stacked');

% Set the filler to transparent
set(h(2),'Face','none','Edge','none')

% Set y-labels
yticks = linspace(0,max(B),5) + mxA;
set(gca,'Ytick', [linspace(0,mxA,5) yticks(2:end)],'YtickL', [linspace(0,mxA,5) yticks(2:end)-mxA])
```

[image]

Comment: Is it possible to make it so that the y values of the bar chart correspond to the number in "A" and "B". I think that your suggestion does show both values of each bar, but these values don't represent the values in "A" and "B". What it does is that it starts counting "A" after "B" and so you get the top of the bar = A+B

Comment: thanks for your suggestion - looks quite good. please let me know if what i am asking is not possible (to have the bars on one chart).

Comment: Do you mean to have the bars **grouped**? Like in bar([A,B])?

Comment: wouldn't that give two bars per x tick?

Comment: Please, take a moment to read the documentation of the function (check out the examples) and come back to ask precisely what you want to achieve.

Comment: thanks I have read the available bar chart. I may be slightly struggling to explain. let me try again

Comment: I am trying to plot a stacked bar chart (with two variables per bar)   The typical stacked bar charts start the second variable (B) not from zero but from the value of the first variable (A).  I do not want this. I want both A and B variables to start from zero

Comment: However, the problem in the original code above is that when the A value is higher than the B value then you cannot see the value of B on the graph. All you know is that it is less than A because it is covered!

Comment: First: 'stack' is NOT the appropriate word. Second: why don't you like having two bars per x tick (the most logical)? Do you want transparency? Or 3D?

Comment: would transparency allow me to show both colours of each variable and at the same time having each variable from 0?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/29031/discussion-between-oleg-komarov-and-user643469)

Comment: all the last bar in your code as h = bar(...); then try set(allchild(h),'FaceAlpha',0.5)